# Cannot sign blackberry 10 app

Tags: blackberry-10, signing, blackberry-world

I'm trying to sign a bb 10 app that is hidden from the home screen (ie there is no icon on the home screen to launch the app).

I get the following error when I try to sign.

Error: Code signing request failed because [hidden] in Entry-Point-System-Actions is not allowed.

Are there some sort of special permissions needed to make you app hidden?

Answer (score 2):

Hidden apps are not permitted on BlackBerry 10. There will be the ability to run an app in the background, while the app is not open in the next few months, but there are no plans to allow apps which don't have any presence on the users home screen.

http://crackberry.com/going-headless-background-app-support-coming-soon-blackberry-10